# Install same application but with different name

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I have made a one application and then copy this application and change the name and icon and then i install this application in phone this replace old application . 
how to change application id ,

how to install two application in phone not remove old install app 
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can change [ProductID -> Packaging in WMAppManifest.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), then you will be able to install the same App on your Developer Phone/Emulator.

You can also change the name in this file: Application UI -> Display Name (you can also change icons there).

When you publish your App, then the new ProductID is created.